# Add STS reference gives error: "The security token service descriptor does not contain any key descriptors"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, azure, wif, accesscontrolservice

When adding an STS reference, I input the my windows azure federation metadata URL and it gives me the error in the title. It works if I create a new namespace, but a lot of stuff is configured on the current namespace, so I can't delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So for anyone that would get this error, it's a simple fix.

You need a X.509 certificate configured as primary in your ACS namespace.

To do this you go under your acs configurations, in certificates and keys then you add a X.509 by uploading a .pfx file to the server and entering the password.

You might also need a symmetric key also set as primary depending on your configuration.